# is it impossible to create an empty array and add a json object to it?

Tags: json, linux, jq

```
for region in $(jq '.data | keys | .[]' <<< "$data"); do
value=$(jq -r ".data[$region]" <<< "$data");
deliveryRegionId=$(jq -r '.deliveryRegionId' <<< "$value");
json_template='{}';
json_data=$(jq --argjson deliveryRegionId "$deliveryRegionId" --arg deliverableDistance 5000 '.deliveryRegionId=$deliveryRegionId | .deliverableDistance=5000' <<<"$json_template"); echo $json_data;
jq '.requestArray += "$json_data" // not work
done;
echo $requestArray
```

I want to add `json_data` to `requestArray`, but it seems not to work.
how can I add `json_data` to `requestArray`?

Comment: Looks like this could be accomplished entirely in jq. Could you provide the initial content of `$data` and your desired outcome?

Comment: ```data:[{"deliveryRegionId":2},{"deliveryRegionId":3"}```

Comment: ```requestArray:[{"deliveryRegionId":2,"deliverableDistance":5000},{"deliveryRegionId":3,"deliverableDistance":5000}]```

Comment: The unnecessary parts of the data were omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this could be accomplished entirely in jq.

Try this to change the `data` field directly:

```sh
jq --argjson deliverableDistance 5000 '
  .data[] += {$deliverableDistance}
' <<< "$data"
```

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "deliveryRegionId": 2,
      "deliverableDistance": 5000
    },
    {
      "deliveryRegionId": 3,
      "deliverableDistance": 5000
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pJqaCapO0J)

Or this, if you want to have the resulting object's field renamed to `requestArray`:

```sh
jq --argjson deliverableDistance 5000 '
  {requestArray: (.data | map(. += {$deliverableDistance}))}
' <<< "$data"
```

```json
{
  "requestArray": [
    {
      "deliveryRegionId": 2,
      "deliverableDistance": 5000
    },
    {
      "deliveryRegionId": 3,
      "deliverableDistance": 5000
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ft8FO2rqpf)

Comment: I want to add json_data to requestArray, which I can't see for requestArray or json_data.

Comment: @김효성 You have never explained what `json_data` is, apart from being used as variable in your shell code. According to that, it is a new object containing `deliveryRegionId` and `deliverableDistance` which in my code is created by `+=` (for the already existing `deliveryRegionId`) and the following object (constructing the `deliverableDistance`).

Comment: Thank you, but is it impossible to create an empty array and add a json object to it?

Comment: Since there are many unnecessary values in the original data, I only want to bring the value ```deliveryRegionId```. I'm also trying to add ```deliveryDistance``` to it.

Comment: @김효성 I think that's exactly what my approach is doing. The (quite simplistic) answer to your your question "is it impossible to create an empty array and add a json object to it" would be `jq -n --argjson obj '{…}' '[$obj]'` but I think you should rephrase that as a new question (or edit this one) to receive an answer more suitable to your needs.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the method?