# How to make a new array and add json value in bash

Tags: json, linux, jq

```
for region in $(jq '.data | keys | .[]' <<< "$data"); do
value=$(jq -r ".data[$region]" <<< "$data");
deliveryRegionId=$(jq -r '.deliveryRegionId' <<< "$value");
json_template='{}';
json_data=$(jq --argjson deliveryRegionId "$deliveryRegionId" --arg deliverableDistance 5000 '.deliveryRegionId=$deliveryRegionId | .deliverableDistance=5000' <<<"$json_template"); echo $json_data;
requestArray=$(jq '. += [$json_data]' <<< $requestArray)
done;
```

As in the code above, I'm going to create a json value called `json_data` and add it to the array.
What should I do to make this work?

```
jq: error: $json_data is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
. += [$json_data]      
jq: 1 compile error
```

this is error

Comment: another solution maybe try using double quotes instead of single quotes in the `requestArray=$(jq '. += [$json_data]' <<< $requestArray)` line.

Comment: @Ozgur Murat, That's awful advice. Don't generate programs from the shell. (And you forgot to replace the quotes with double-quotes.)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70828479/589924

Comment: `--argjson deliveryRegionId "$deliveryRegionId"` is wrong. Should be just `--arg` since `$deliveryRegionId` is text not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There's no jq variable named `$json_data`.

There is a shell variable named that, but you can't access another program's variables.

**Provide the value via the environment**

```sh
json_data="$json_data" jq '. += [ env.json_data ]' <<<"$requestArray"
```

**Provide the value via the environment**

```sh
export json_data
jq '. += [ env.json_data ]' <<<"$requestArray"
```

**Provide the value as an argument**

```sh
jq --arg json_data "$json_data" '. += [ $json_data ]' <<<"$requestArray"
```

---

There's no reason to use `jq` so many times! Your entire program can be replaced with this:

```sh
requestArray="$(
   jq '.data | map( { deliveryRegionId, deliverableDistance: 5000 } )' \
      <<<"$data"
)"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JcZyEPMCbw) on jqplay